# How to calculate the probability that an algorithm classifies seven wines out of ten correctly when the true error is 0.23?

Tags: self-study, bayes

I am considering the following problem.

> Calculate the exact probability that an algorithm classifies seven
>   wines out of ten correctly when the true error is 0.23.

Should I solve this with Bayes' rule?

Answer (score 2):

To apply Bayes formula you need prior probabilities. No priors, no Bayes.

Assuming that true error is the probability of mis-classification of the algorithm and that wines are classified independently of each other, you can compute this probability as a Binomial variable with paramters n=10 and p=.23 (counting failures), which does not require Bayes rule.

Comment: Where does "the true error is 0.23" come in to the calculation you have described?

Comment: I don't see it neither, can you be a little more specific? Why is 9 out of 10 not possible?

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate thanks! You are right that I missed that. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The probability the algorithm works an any particular case is $1-0.23=0.77$.  Assuming the algorithm works independently on each case, the answer is $${10 \choose 7} 0.77^7 0.23^3 \approx 0.2343$$

Comment: (1) Please see our [homework policy](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12). (2) The question did not ask for a numerical answer.